# SQL Agent cannot access UNC share

Tags: sql-server, ssis, permissions, sql-server-agent

I have a SSIS package which creates a folder in an UNC share and then creates a file there (using script task).

The domain account which is used by SSIS and Agent has all the possible permissions in the DB computer and the share computer.

It always fails there.

I created a test SQL Agent job which creates a backup of the database in the same location and it fails too (Operating system error 5 - access denied).

EDIT: The above test example may be irrelevant since the backup operation is executed by SQL Server Database Engine and not the SQL Agent itself (Agent still schedules the task).

I cannot debug the script task in SSIS and therefore Im not sure what is the problem.

Comment: try in local server where sql agent is create file. if this works, try to give that job account which is in Administrators group in share computer...

Comment: What is the error message exactly (could you please post it, obscuring any names)?  If you are getting access denied, which user account is being denied?  Where is the package in relationship to the db server?  Is it on the same server or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem. The first problem was lack of sufficient task activation/execution permissions in the DCOM config node in Component Services. The permissions had to be set for SQL Server Integration Services.

The second problem was the fact that the UNC path looked like this:

> \\192.168.250.51\C$\Folder\

I needed to create another share (visible) like that:

> \\COMPUTER-NAME\Folder\

Also don't try to map any drives to the folders. It won't work.